# Selecting all checkboxes inside ng-grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-grid

I found some jsfiddle jquery code and tried to combine it with my `ng-grid` to select all checkboxes within the grid. However, it is not working.

Here is a quick mockup of what i tried to do:

http://plnkr.co/edit/zy653RrqHmBiRJ7xDHlV?p=preview

this is my directive

```
  (function(){
     var app = angular.module('provider-selectall', []);
      app.directive('selectAll',function(){
       return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attr){
         element.click(function() {
         $('.ngSelectionCheckbox input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
        });
      }
    };
  });     
})();
```

the button that will activated by the directive

```
 <div class="btn-group">
  <button class="my-btn btn-info" select-all>Select All</button>
  </button>
</div>
```

stuff within my ng-grid controller

```
  var checkBoxCellTemplate = '<div class="ngSelectionCell"><input tabindex="-1" class="ngSelectionCheckbox" type="checkbox" ng-checked="row.selected" /></div>';
  $scope.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    {
      cellTemplate: checkBoxCellTemplate,
      showSelectionCheckbox: true
    },{
      field: 'name',
      displayName: 'CPT Code/Description'
    },{
      field: 'cash_price',
      displayName: 'Cash Price'
    },{
      field: 'average_price',
      displayName: 'Average Price'
    },

  ],
  data: 'provider_medical_services'
```

original jsfiddle code:

```
$('#toggle-all').click(function() {
  $('.btn-group input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$('.ngViewport.ng-scope input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: can you explain how it is like that?

Comment: Because all checkboxes are render inside individual parent div. and all these divs are wrapped in another div with class `ngViewport` and `ng-scope`

Comment: where can i find the documentation for this??

Comment: Documentation for what?? it did not worked due to incorrect selector.

Comment: im still confused how you saw the checkboxes were wrapped in divs ngViewport and ng-scope

Comment: @ApprenticeProgrammer: by inspecting rendered html in console.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $('.ngSelectionCell.ng-scope input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
```

### [Updated Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/3DuzftP1GZbuJoPqpNdx?p=preview)

Comment: actulay btn-group is not parent for any input type of  check box.but i sseen .ng-scope contains all check box .that s y i suggested

Comment: have look at rendered dom.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar  have you look my answer .now i updated.. again you have to look rendered dom element ..i think it is good  compared to your post